# Simulating moving geolocation when developing web map solution using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, testing, geolocation, openlayers

Long title but simple problem that I really haven't found a good solution to.

**Prerequisites**

- ASP.NET Framework Web Forms Application (not really important)
- Map solution using **OpenLayers** 2.14 (yeah I know it's old but it works)

I'm currently implementing a feature that will display the current position of the device in map and it's based on the **Geolocate**-control of OpenLayers. It works great for the initial load but I would like to simulate a person moving around geographically with their device for testing purposes.

**What I've tried**

- I've tried using the **Sensors**-feature of **DevTools**. Again, this works for the initial load, changing the location requires a refresh of the page.
- I've tried using Selenium ChromeDriver to send the coordinates with the command: `Emulation.setGeolocationOverride`, but this does not trigger `watchPosition` being updated for `navigator.geolocation`.
- Can't find any suitable **Chrome Extension** for the problem.

Does anyone know of any best practice for this problem? At the moment I have to revert to some refactoring and simulate some updates using `setInterval`. This however won't fully test the behavior of the `navigator.geolocation`-feature without me running around with my developer-device in the wild.

Comment: You could try using a mock location app on the device, such as these for Android https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mock+location&c=apps&hl=en_UShttps://play.google.com/store/search?q=mock+location&c=apps&hl=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone working with OpenLayers 2.x I would like to add that you can save yourself a lot of headache by specifying the `watch`-property to true using the **Geolocate**-control. This is by default `false` which caused a lot of testing  to fail. Simple testing using the **Sensors**-feature of DevTools works as intended if the `watch`-property is set.